# how to count a total number in a matrix row using c#

Tags: c#

So how to count the total number in the first row of matrix a and put it in the matrix b.

Example :

matrix a : 3 2 1

and output of matrix b will be like : 3+6 2+6 1+6

```
        Console.Write("Matriks A\n");
        Console.WriteLine("------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (a = 0; a < baris; a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b < kolom; b++)
            {
                Console.Write(" Matriks A [" + (a + 0) + "][" + (b + 0) + "] = ");
                matrik_a[a, b] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Matriks B ");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

        for (a = 0; a < baris; a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b < kolom; b++)
            {

                matrik_b[a, b] = matrik_a[a, b] + matrik_b[a, b];
                Console.Write("{0:d}\t", matrik_b[a, b]);


            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What's your exact problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a loop for each row, save the total to a var and put in the other matrix, all this in one iteration.

The complexity stay the same since 2 * O(n) = O(n)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int baris = 2, kolom = 2, a=0, b=0;
        Console.Write("Matriks A\n");
        Console.WriteLine("------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        int[,] matrik_a = new int[3, 3];
        int[,] matrik_b = new int[3, 3];

        for (a = 0; a <= baris; a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b <= kolom; b++)
            {
                Console.Write(" Matriks A [" + (a + 0) + "][" + (b + 0) + "] = ");
                matrik_a[a, b] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Matriks B ");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

        int sumOfRow = 0;
        for (a = 0; a <= baris; a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b <= kolom; b++)
            {
                sumOfRow += matrik_a[a, b];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("sum of row " + a.ToString() + "is: " + sumOfRow.ToString());
            for (b = 0; b <= kolom; b++)
            {
                matrik_b[a, b] = matrik_a[a, b] + sumOfRow;
            }
            sumOfRow = 0;
        }

        for (a = 0; a <= baris; a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b <= kolom; b++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrik_b[a, b]);
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but changing your second section of loop to below should work:

```
for (a = 0; a < baris; a++)
{
    int rowSum = 0; //Below loop can be avoided using LINQ
    for (b = 0; b < kolom; b++)
    {
      rowSum += matrik_a[a, b];
    }
    for (b = 0; b < kolom; b++)
    {
        matrik_b[a, b] = matrik_a[a, b] + rowSum;
        Console.Write("{0:d}\t", matrik_b[a, b]);
    }
}
```